# Sort dictionary values and discard those which do not have a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following function that takes a dictionary, sort it and return the list of dictionary values.

```
def sort_dict_values(dic):
keys = dic.keys()
keys.sort()
return map(dic.get, keys)

dict1 = {"b":"1", "a":"2", "d":"", "c":"3"}
sorted_list = sort_dict_values(dict1)
```

This function returns a list including items with an empty value. e.g. the resulting list will be:

```
["2","1","3",""]
```

I want to discard items which don't have a value. e.g. discard "d" since it is empty. Resulting list shall look like:

```
["2","1","3"]
```

Comment: dict1 = {"b","1", "a","2", "d","", "c","3"} is not a dictionary, it is a set.

Comment: Also, you should not use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: @theAlse I've fixed that, for some reason a lot of people like to hand write all their input data in their questions, although they usually mean what you think they mean, anyway that I will never understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> dict1 = {"b":"1", "a":"2", "d":"", "c":"3"}
>>> [v for k, v in sorted(dict1.items()) if v]
['2', '1', '3']
```

As @AlexChamberlain said in the comments, it would reduce the load on the O(N log N) sorting algorithm, by performing the O(N) filter first

```
>>> [v for k, v in sorted(x for x in dict1.items() if x[1])]
['2', '1', '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` here:

```
from itertools import imap
def sort_dict_values(dic):
    keys = dic.keys()
    keys.sort()
    return filter(None,imap(dic.get, keys))

dict1 = {"b":"1", "a":"2", "d":"", "c":"3"}
print sort_dict_values(dict1)   
#['2', '1', '3']
```

or as suggested by @Alex Chamberlain it would be better filter keys before sorting as that would reduce the number of items to be sorted:

```
def sort_dict_values(dic):
    keys = sorted(k for k,v in dic.iteritems() if v !='')
    return map(dic.get, keys)

dict1 = {"b":"1", "a":"2", "d":"", "c":"3"}
print sort_dict_values(dict1) 
#['2', '1', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

simply filter the result of sorting

```
>>> a = ["2","1","3",""]
>>> filter(None, a)
['2', '1', '3']
```

Comment: `filter(None, a)` is the standard way to do that. docstring quote: "If function is None, return the items that are true."

Comment: @kampu `filter(bool` is also a standard

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
[v for k,v in sorted(zip(d.keys(),d.values())) if v]
```

Comment: Correct however `dict.items()` does `zip(d.keys(), d.values())` for you

Comment: True :) I adapted a two list sort approach, but items is actually a lot better, thanks